# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError:

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting below exception while I am adding one java module as the dependency of the project.

Exception is :

ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed 
to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/PoolStats;)Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/MetricsTracker;\n
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)\n  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
    instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)\n   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)\n
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)\n at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.
    createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)\n
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)\n at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)\n at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)\n  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)\n    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)\n   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)\n    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)\n    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)\n   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)\n at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)\n  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)\n at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)\n    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)\n    at com.jpmc.gicb.wfxRequests.WFXRequestApplication.main(WFXRequestApplication.java:17)\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/PoolStats;)Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/MetricsTracker;\n at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)\n    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)\n  ... 18 common frames omitted\nCaused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.zaxxer.hikari.metrics.micrometer.MicrometerMetricsTrackerFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/PoolStats;)Lcom/zaxxer/hikari/metrics/MetricsTracker;\n    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.setMetricsTrackerFactory(HikariPool.java:273)\n    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)\n  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97)\n at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)\n  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)\n  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)\n at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:323)\n  at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:123)\n   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42)\n  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$0(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132)\n  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:53)\n at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.determineDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:247)\n    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getAdditionalProperties(JpaProperties.java:216)\n at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.access$000(JpaProperties.java:169)\n  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(JpaProperties.java:153)\n    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:134)\n   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:136)\n    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75e195f5.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$6()\n    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75e195f5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7290b124.invoke()\n    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)\n  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)\n at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$75e195f5.entityManagerFactory()\n    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)\n    ... 19 common frames omitted\n
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57203', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

I know , this is dependency problem.I have browsed other stackoverflow questions but nothing seems to work.

**pom.xml of main project**

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.something</groupId>
            <artifactId>other-project-data</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.53</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**pom of other-project-data**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.something</groupId>
            <artifactId>other-project-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>63.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${app.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>jazzy-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/${app.lib}/jazzy-core-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${app.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/${app.lib}/aspose-cells-8.7.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${app.group.id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/${app.lib}/commons-io-1.4.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**pom of other-project-commons**

```
<properties>
<hibernate.version>3.2.1.GA</hibernate.version>
</properties>
    <dependencies>

    <!-- add ons -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ibatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>ibatis-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- add ons -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>${antlr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>${asm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
        <version>${strutsframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${jta.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-spec-javamail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>${standard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- QuartzJobBean in spring-context-support.jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Batch dependencies --><!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- ******* Libraries required for Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
        <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId>
        <version>${csrfguard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Specific to Project 1 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.antisamy</groupId>
        <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>batik-util</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>batik-css</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-full</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-adapters</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.j2ee</groupId>
        <artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>avalon-logkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-logkit</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc6</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0-Production</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.crystaldecisions</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl-2.8.1</artifactId>
        <version>12.3.1.684</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anybody please guide me if there is any problem with hibernate dependencies or how can  I resolve the issue.

**EDIT**
In commons pom I see that there is conflict showing for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

[image]

I have added a screenshot , please let me know if I need to change something.This dependency is also present in main project . I tried to comment that out and run the project but still same error , I am getting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove explicit dependency of "hibernate core" from common pom.xml.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.18.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Spring JPA dependency added in main pom.xml should bring hibernate dependencies.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The above dependency will include JPA API, JPA Implementation, JDBC and other needed libraries. Since the default JPA implementation is Hibernate, this dependency is actually enough to bring it.

Comment: Ganesh, I did that but it is still failing. Have edited my question , can you please check if I need to change the version of spring-data-jpa or need to exclude something.Thanks